# Cronjobs at night - but not the rest of the day

Tags: wp-cron, automation

I have a cronjob, that at the moment runs hourly - I would probably prefer it to only run hourly between 2am and 5am.

Is that possible with some kind of scheduling to tell Wordpress, that it is hourly only between 2am and 5am?
Or should I just make 3 "schedules" daily (so one daily at 2am, one at 3am, one at 4am and last at 5am)?

The last solution seems a bit strange, but maybe it is just the only way around it?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/422016/edit) to clarify: Do you mean [WordPress's Cron system](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/), which will *only* run if a page is loaded, or your host server's `cron` daemon (or other scheduling system)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the behavior you're describing in WordPress, where a cron job runs hourly but only between 2 AM and 5 AM, you have a couple of options. While WordPress doesn't offer this level of specificity in its default scheduling, you can customize it to suit your needs.

Custom Cron Scheduling: This involves creating a custom cron schedule in WordPress that checks the current time and then decides whether to run the task. Here's an outline of how you might implement it:

Create a function that hooks into the 'cron_schedules' filter to add a custom schedule that runs hourly.
In your scheduled event's callback function, check if the current time is between 2 AM and 5 AM. If it is, execute the task; if not, do nothing.

Here's a basic example in PHP:

Add this to your themes functions.php file at the bottom. (Use a child theme if you can)

```
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'wpb_custom_cron_schedule');
function wpb_custom_cron_schedule($schedules) {
    $schedules['hourly_2am_5am'] = array(
        'interval' => 3600, // Every hour
        'display' => __('Hourly between 2 AM and 5 AM')
    );
    return $schedules;
}

add_action('wpb_hourly_event', 'wpb_do_this_hourly');
function wpb_do_this_hourly() {
    $current_hour = date('G'); // 'G' format will return hours in 24-hour format without leading zeros

    if ($current_hour >= 2 && $current_hour <= 5) {
        // Your code here
    }
}

if (!wp_next_scheduled('wpb_hourly_event')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly_2am_5am', 'wpb_hourly_event');
}
```

Multiple Daily Schedules: As you mentioned, another way is to schedule the event to run daily at specific times (2 AM, 3 AM, 4 AM, and 5 AM). This is a bit redundant but works if you prefer a more straightforward approach.

Each of these methods has its advantages. The custom cron scheduling offers more flexibility and is more efficient, as it involves fewer scheduled tasks. The multiple daily schedules method is simpler and might be easier to manage if you're not comfortable with more complex code.

Remember to replace the placeholder comments and function names with your actual task logic and appropriate naming conventions.